# Raspberry Pi goes blank after 10 mins or so, until the resolution is changed. and repeats

Tags: hdmi, screen, screen-saver

so I just got a really cheap and free desktop monitor from work, that's like 1280x1024 resolution.

Now when I first connected the pi to the monitor it failed to boot at all... which was weird, but then I hooked it up to my tv via hdmi to micro hdmi and then it worked. After that, I tried connecting the pi back to the monitor, and surprisingly it started working. However, now the problem becomes is that, The pi shows the screen it stays conencted, and works for good 10ish minutes, but after the that it just goes blank. 
At that point, I have to connect to my Pi using vnc, and then change the resolution of my pi from settings, and it would show to screen, and then change it back to 1280x1024, and again after 10ish minutes it goes back to being blank, until I do the fix again.

Is there a way I can solve this problem for good?

NOTE: the monitor only has displayport, VGA and DVI, and I have an hdmi to DVI converter, which I then connect to my Amazon Basics micro-hdmi to hdmi cable.

Comment: Is there any "blank display" after 10 minutes active, maybe at the driver or on a screensaver?

Comment: I experienced twice this kind of problem a couple of years ago, and the causes I found surprising to me.  (1) My video cable has bent too much, and the broken apart cable has two broken end in contact, but when heated up (after a couple of seconds) loses contact and signal lost.  I finally swapped a good cable and the problem disappeared (of course to make sure I swapped the bad cable and the probem came back.)

Comment: (2) Often electronic equipment do age.  One problem is that when some aged components heats up will become crazy, but go back to normal when cooled down. (So when you swap things, you are allowing time for some aged components to cool down) Of course there are other reasons causing trouble.